What is the meaning of $\asymp$ and $\lesssim$ in Martin wainwright's high dim textbook?
Unfortunately, this text book did not provide a table of notations he used.
Can anyone provide me with a definition of $\asymp$ and $\lesssim$ and few examples?
For an example in the book, in display (5.5), let $N(\delta)$ denote the $\delta$-covering number, the $\delta$-covering number of the $d$-dim cube satisfies
$$
\log N(\delta; [0,1]^d) \asymp d \log(\frac{1}{\delta}),
$$
for $\delta$ sufficiently small.
what exactly is the meaning of $\asymp$ here?

For those who don't have the book memorized (or have it at all), it may be helpful to provide an example passage or two containing each symbol. That way, we can infer the meaning from context and explain.

I'm fairly sure $A\lesssim B$ means there exists a universal constant $K$ such that $A< KB$; it's a uniform version of big-O notation. Similarly, $A\asymp B$ means that there are universal constants $k$ and $K$ such that $kA < B <KA$, so it's a uniform version of asymptotic equivalence.
These seem to first occur in Chapter 5, and I couldn't find a definition in the book. For people who want examples, $\asymp$ is in display 5.5 and $\lesssim$  is in display 5.29.
